# proposition question: If X has exponential distribution with mean $\theta$, then E(X)= $\theta$, Var(X)= $\theta^2$, $M_X(t)$=$\frac{1}{1-\theta t}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> If X has exponential distribution with mean $\theta$, then E(X)= $\theta$, Var(X)= $\theta^2$, $M_X(t)$=$\frac{1}{1-\theta t}$
>
> Proof: $M_X(t)$=$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{tx} \frac{1}{\theta} e^\frac{-x}{\theta} dx $=[$\frac{1}{\theta}$*$\frac{1}{t-\frac{1}{\theta}}$* $e^{(t-\frac{1}{\theta})x}$]$^{\infty}_{x=0}$
>
> If t<$\frac{1}{\theta}$, then $M_X(t)$= $\frac{1}{1-\theta t}$

I don't understand why t<$\frac{1}{\theta}$, so we can approach 0? What's the significance of moment generating function with $t=0$ in general?

Comment: $M_X(0) = \mathbb E[\exp(0\cdot X)] = \mathbb E[1] = 1$, always. At your problem, we can evaluate that integral when it is convergent. It is convergent if and only if that term in $\exp$ near $x$ is les than zero, so when $t-\frac{1}{\theta} < 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $t > \frac{1}\theta$, then your intégrand becomes $\frac{1}{\theta} \exp\left((t-\frac{1}\theta)x \right) = \frac{1}\theta e^{\alpha x}$ where $\alpha>0$ and so the integral diverges.